# Using RSolve to solve a recurrence relation

Tags: equation-solving, recursion, difference-equations

I am attempting to solve this recurrence relation.

```
T[n] = n^(1.5) + T[n - 4]
```

which I believe simplifies to

```
n^(2.5)
```

I have tried solving is a couple different ways with no success.

```
RSolve[T[n - 4] + n^(1.5) == 1, T[n], n]
```

> Error: RSolve: n cannot be used as a function

```
RSolve[{T[n] == T[n - 4] + n^(1.5), T[1] = 1}, T[n], n]
```

> Equation or list of equations expected instead of 1 in the first argument {n == n^(1.5) + T[-4 + n], 1}.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Use == instead of = in T[1]=1. This solves the problem, but the result looks much more complicated than your expected n^(2.5). Are you missing out on any assumptions ?

Comment: @Lotus That output is not like anything I was expecting. What sort of assumptions would you recommend? trying Assumptions -> n > 0 didn't work, it said there was an unknown option Assumptions in RSolve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, test the solution suggested in the question by evaluating the first several terms of the recurrence.

```
T[1] = 1
T[n_] := T[n - 4] + n^1.5
Table[T[n], {n, 1, 21, 4}]
(* {1, 12.1803, 39.1803, 86.0525, 156.145, 252.379} *)
```

and contrast this with the first several terms of the proposed solution.

```
Table[n^(2.5), {n, 1, 21, 4}]
(* {1., 55.9017, 243., 609.338, 1191.58, 2020.92} *)
```

They are not the same.  Instead, the correct solution is obtained with `RSolve` by first substituting `n == 4 m - 3` (valid, because `T[n]` is defined only for `Mod[n, 4] == 1`).

```
Clear[T]
Simplify[T[m] /. First@RSolve[{T[m] == T[m - 1] + (4 m - 3)^1.5, T[1] == 1}, T[m], m]]
(* -0.120874 - 8. HurwitzZeta[-1.5, 0.25 + m] *)
```

the correctness of which can be verified by

```
Table[%, {m, 6}]
(* {1., 12.1803, 39.1803, 86.0525, 156.145, 252.379} *)
```

as desired.

Comment: also, with exact coefficients, `1+8HurwitzZeta[-(3/2),5/4]-8HurwitzZeta[-(3/2),1/4+m]`